# Server.Transfer("error_404.aspx") in Application_Error returns a blank page

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, http-status-codes, httpexception, application-error

I look for HttpExceptions in the Application_Error sub of my global.asx

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim ex As Exception = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError()

        If ex IsNot Nothing Then
            If TypeOf (ex) Is HttpUnhandledException Then
                If ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then
                    Server.Transfer("error.aspx", False)
                End If
                ex = ex.InnerException
            End If

            If TypeOf (ex) Is HttpException Then
                Dim httpCode As Integer = CType(ex, HttpException).GetHttpCode()
                If httpCode = 404 Then
                    Server.ClearError()
                    Server.Transfer("error_404.aspx", False)
                End If
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

I can step through this code and confirm it does hit the Server.Transfer("error_404.aspx"), as well as the Page_Load of error_404.aspx, but all it shows is a blank page.

Comment: Make sure to add a call to your error logging system. If an unhandled exception happens, you want to know so you can go handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you clearing the Response buffer?  You have no clue what is already there, since you are doing this in the Application_Error catch-all.  Server.Transfer just appends whatever the new page generates onto the existing Response.  Obviously this could create some issues.

Comment: this is essentially what was happening. server.transfer was throwing an exception because its output buffer was not empty

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change the `Server.Transfer` to a `Response.Redirect`?   (You may have to use the HTTPContext.Current prefix from where you are in global.asax.)

I'm not sure that a Server.Transfer is a good idea in the context of what you're doing, since you're effectively asking IIS to render the global.asax URL to the browser.

Comment: if I use Response.Redirect it generates a HTTP 302 and then redirects to error_404.aspx. I want to generate a single 404 request and display the contents of the error_404.aspx while keeping the url the same as the original reqest. per your second comment, how am I asking IIS to render the global.asax? I thought Server.Transfer("error_404.aspx") means it would ask IIS to render error_404.aspx

Comment: Makes sense..  I managed to make two mistakes in that small post.   Perhaps I'll delete and await the real answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think if some error occurs, Server.Transfer won't fire.

[Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800.aspx) is not a good method for this. Try with [Response.Redirect](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=response.redirect&ac=1). It should work.

If you have any exception is there any requirement for maintaining the states? If not, go with `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: like i said to LesterDove, if I use a Response.Redirect, I end up with 2 responses. The original page, which 302 redirects to error_404.aspx. I want to generate a single 404 response